# How do I use strpos to match common spam fields in my database to a form submission?

Tags: php, mysql, strpos

I get a few spam responses to my web contact form and I've used these to build up a list of fields to filter on. My plan was to compare - using strpos - each field against the text field submitted by the user and, if there's a match, redirect that mail response.

For whatever reason, the code I'm trying just doesn't seem to hit a match; what am I missing?

```
// Query list of spam fields
    $sqlSpam= "SELECT * FROM tblspamfilter";  
    $rstSpam= mysqli_query($db, $sqlSpam);

// Search for key in the notes field passed by the web form 
    while ($rowSpam=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rstSpam)) {
        $Key= $rowSpam['Key'];
        if (strpos($notes, $Key) === false) {
            $spam=0;
            } else {
            $spam++;
            }
        }

if ($spam==0) {
    // send the mail...
    } else {
    // not today Mr spammer
    }
```

It worked OK as a static spam key, but noyt now that I've added teh database element. Nothing I try in my form submission field (exact match, part match etc. ) matches as a spam event and all the mail gets through. I'm quite new to php so I assume I'm missing something in the way it compares the data from the table?

Edit:
I have the following fields in my spam table:

```
| idKey | Key | 
| 1 | jnl.io | 
| 2 | drive.google.com | 
| 3 | casinogorilla.com | 
| 4 | www.talkwithcustomer.com | 
| 5 | sexy | 
| 6 | profitable database of email addresses | 
| 7 | My name is Roy | 
| 8 | Sexy girls |
```

And using this code:

```
$spamWords = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rstSpam);
$spam = 0;
foreach ($spamWords as $spamWord) {
    if (strpos($notes, $spamWord) !== false) {
        $spam++;
    }
}
```

I get a match for jnl.io, drive.google.com but not for www.talkwithcustomer.com, sexy etc. I don't see a pattern for it at all. Is there a size limit? Is strpos the wrong technique?

**Working Code**
The following is now working; not sure exactly what fixed it, but there was an odd collation for the table which I have replaced with *utf8_general_ci* and this, amongst the other suggestions has got it testing OK. Many thanks for looking in.

```
// Check the notes field for any likely spam indicators
    $spam=0;
    while ($rowSpam=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rstSpam)) {
        $Key= $rowSpam['Key'];
        if (strpos($notes, $Key) !== false) {
            $spam++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, at least, dont set $spam to zero, if the last keyword isnt in message, you will validate it as notspam, set it to zero before while cycle and than just increment, dont set again

Comment: I've tried that as well and it gives the same result

`$spam=0;
while ($rowSpam=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rstSpam)) {
 $Key= $rowSpam['Key'];
 if (strpos($notes, $Key) === true) {
  $spam++;
  }
 }
`

Comment: dont use === true, you need to use !== false due to strpos return values

Comment: Thanks; using !== false works, mostly. 

This way (and your code below) catch the phrases of **jnl.io** and **drive.google.com** but not the single word **sexy**

Is this an aspect of strpos I'm not aware of?

Comment: I dont think so, when you edit the code below and add word sexy to $spamWords and also to $spamMessage, strpos will correctly detect this word. This could be some issue maybe with encoding/characters (some characters looks exactly same but are not same) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Example code, where you can see your approach vs. the right approach to this problem...
https://3v4l.org/Yidr1

```
<?php

$spamWords = ['blah', 'nah', 'hah', 'spam', 'spamm'];

$spamMessage = 'Here we go blah blah blah';

// this is the way you do this
$spam = 0;
foreach ($spamWords as $spamWord) {
    if (strpos($spamMessage, $spamWord) === false) {
        echo 'This keyword aint here, previous value - ' . $spam . PHP_EOL;
        $spam = 0;
    } else {
        $spam++;
        echo 'I am spam' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

if ($spam === 0) {
    echo 'not spam' . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'spam' . PHP_EOL;
}
// well obviously, you will echo 'spam' only if lastword from your spam-words will be present
// so you need to keep your variable
echo 'Right approach' . PHP_EOL;
$spam = 0;
foreach ($spamWords as $spamWord) {
    if (strpos($spamMessage, $spamWord) !== false) {
        $spam++;
    }
}
// now works as expected
if ($spam === 0) {
    echo 'not spam';
} else {
    echo 'spam';
}
```